# how to concat mat in opencv without copying both data

Tags: opencv

I want to concat many images, and each time with one image concat to the previous concated image.
Now I implement it like this:

```
cv::Mat src1;

cv::Mat concatImage(cv::Mat src2)
{
   cv::Mat outImg(src1.rows, src1.cols+src2.cols);
   cv::Mat outImg1 = outImg(cvRect(0, 0, src1.rows, src1.cols));
   cv::Mat outImg2 = outImg(cvRect(src1.cols, 0, src2.rows, src2.cols));
   src1.copyTo(outImg1);
   src2.copyTo(outImg2);

   src1 = outImg;
   return src1;
}
```

concatImage will be called several times, but I will not know the number advanced, and each time it is called, I have to return the contactedImage. Therefore, I can not buffer all the images, and malloc outImg just for just one time.

As The above code shows, each time, I have to both copy left and right images to outImg.

My question is, can I enlarge the dimension of the mat without destroying its contents, so that I can only copy src2's data to src1.

Answer (score 0):

The data of a Mat is stored in memory in a continuous array in this order:

row1 + row2  + row3  ...

Each row contains a number of pixels equal to the number of columns (plus some padding)

To enlarge an image horizontally, each row needs to be longer. So all subsequent rows would have to be moved in memory.

So increasing the columns of an an image in-place is not possible.

Increasing the number of columns might be feasible, however I am not aware of any opencv method to do so.

But concatenating images horizontally like you do would mean increasing the number of columns, so this would not help anyway.

If possible, I would recommend collecting all images to be concatenated, and then creating the outimage after you know the full dimensions. Alternatively, you could create the outImage with some reasonable surplus in columns, and only switch to a new outImage when you run out of columns.